# MySql - Is there a way to reverse to use old password?

Tags: mysql

I downloaded the latest MySQL connector for .Net and I got this error "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords."

I found a StackOverflow post on how to fix it so I stupidly logged in as root with Sqlyog and run these two quires:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('[your password]');
```

Now I can't log in as root. Is there a way to reverse it back to use old_password? The root password length is 41 from 16. I can't upgrade every users password because there are other users using it and I don't want to break. What's my option here? Can I use instance config wizard to change root password?

**EDIT**: My server is Win2003 Standard, IIS6 and I can have admin access to the server.

Comment: restart mysql server with passwords disabled and reset the root password

Comment: Is the mysql server a linux box? If yes, do you have root access to it?

Comment: Win2003 Standard and I have admin access to it. Can you show me or point me to how to reset password on Win2003?

Comment: http://butastrangerhere.blogspot.com/2010/05/reset-mysql-root-password-on-windows.html

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explains how to [reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows). The summary is to create a file containing SQL statements to set the password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then stop `mysqld`, and manually start it again, but telling it to execute this SQL file:

```
sudo -u mysqld mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init
```

Comment: Hi, your link didn't say anything about old_password. If I reset root password, would it fix the old_password set to false? Sorry, I'm not a admin but a developer. My server is Win2003.

Comment: @Jack Add the SQL to change `old_passwords` to that file.

Comment: Thanks go out to Daniel T and mgorven. What I found out that work is combined both their answers. Follow Daniel's link [to change my.ini setting](http://butastrangerhere.blogspot.com/2010/05/reset-mysql-root-password-on-windows.html) then on the step of running update query use mgorven's answer. UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: Glad this resolved your issue. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted when you're able](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).